# Why does NetBeans use Tomcat Manager (and Eclipse does not)?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, deployment

As a long-time J2EE developer, I have always been curious as to why NetBeans uses(i.e. forces you to use) the Tomcat Manager app to deploy while Eclipse seems perfectly happy/able to deploy without the manager app?  Though I have googled this exhaustively over the years, I have never found even the beginning to an answer.  Perhaps this is nothing more than how each product started and has never changed.

Does anyone have any insight or educated theories they would be willing to share?

[Edit] Sigh... to address shekhar's comment, I see that it is not absolutely clear that I am referring ONLY to using Tomcat.  I mistakenly assumed that the title and context of my question was sufficient, but again, I am specifically referring to using Tomcat as the Servlet Container with these IDEs.  Thanks.

[Edit] I don't know who down-voted this but I **have** researched this for a long time and found **zero** reason for it.  As for down-voting because it might not be useful, I think that is in the eye of the beholder; also, it usefulness can only be determined based on the answer which is why I am asking.

Comment: NetBeans doesn't force you to use TomcatManager,there is Glassfish server too and both of them are optional...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good topic for Quora but anyway...

I can only speak about NetBeans. It originally used a patched version of Tomcat 3. (early NetBeans 3.x releases). Tomcat Manager was added in Tomcat 4 and it was used because it was possible to integrate easily with your Tomcat installation without knowing much details about their setup. Start/stop Tomcat can use default scripts and will pick up your settings. Deploy does not need to care about access rights and it just assumes that manager works.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply.  Second, I do not know what Quora is (should I?).  Finally, I am hoping to get some clarification; particularly, about your last statement.  Lets start with "Deploy does not need to care about access rights" - Every time I start Tomcat via NetBeans it requires admin username and password so I am a bit confused as to what you mean.  (As a new user, I want to be clear that I am not trying to be argumentative but rather drill down to an answer that I understand)

Comment: I think I might offer a guess as to what you mean and present other readers with a little more info.  I think what you are saying is "Netbeans' use of Tomcat manager is relying on me (the user) to have Tomcat setup 'properly' including the manager app.  From that assumption, NetBeans can simply use Tomcat start/stop scripts and have no need for other Tomcat information/setup.

Comment: ... (continued) As opposed to other approaches (such as Eclipse) that might rely on deploying the .war to a directory and assume that Tomcat is configured to auto-explode the .war.  As you say, this second approach 'might' run into [file/directory] access right issues which would be confusing and possibly difficult for the user to resolve in a multi-user environment such as linux.